# Al llamar el logo que personalizamos en wordpress no me aplica estilo

Tags: php, wordpress

Me estoy haciendo una plantilla con materializecss, el problema viene cuando decido hacer el logo del tema dinámico para que se pueda cambiar desde el mismo wordpress. Vale, el problema es que si yo ahora lo quiero poner un id con los estilos en la imagen o la imagen dentro de un div con dicho id, no me aplica esos estilos, directamente en el inspector de elementos no se visualiza.

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

```
        <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">

        <div id="logo">
            <img id="logo" alt=""><?php the_custom_logo(); ?></img>
        </div>
    <?php
        // Si no hay logo personalizado, solo mostrara el titulo de la pagina
        if (!has_custom_logo()) {
    ?>
            <h1><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></h1>
            <?php
        }
    ?></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los IDs tienen que ser únicos en la página.

Y no hace falta que uses un id para la imagen, esta regla sería suficiente:

```css
#logo img { 
   /* CSS */
}
```

Documentación: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Atributos_Globales/id